# How transfer SPL tokens from PDA to usual account in clean RUST?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, rust, pda, spl

I have PDA created in JS this way:

```
let [pda, bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [baseAccount.publicKey.toBuffer(), Buffer.from('1', 'utf8')],
    programIdPublicKey
);
```

`baseAccount` is a usual Solana account.

I send a transaction to execute my Solana program from JS this way:

```
let transaction = new Transaction().add(
    new TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [
            {
                pubkey: new PublicKey('F69KXy28w8o8XDZYDPJ2axUiJKBLoaPtTuBJRBMLAtWg'), // Token Account where stores PDA tokens
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: true,
            },
            {
                pubkey: mint, // Public key of this Token
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
            {
                pubkey: new PublicKey('C12wxNFqMoAVGiWfkFWcPmVShJvXb3AuHBfK5kYJufS7'), // Token Account of the baseAccount, where exists such tokens
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: true,
            },
            {
                pubkey: mintInfo.mintAuthority, // Public key of the authority of the Token
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
            {
                pubkey: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // SPL Token Program ID
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
            {
                pubkey: baseAccount.publicKey,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
            {
                pubkey: pda,
                isSigner: false,
                isWritable: false,
            },
        ],
        data: data, // Encoded seed and bump of the PDA
        programId: programIdPublicKey,
    })
);
let trxHash = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [baseAccount],
    { commitment: 'finalized' }
);
```

In Solana program I have such code:

```
ProgramInstruction::Withdraw { seed, bump } => {
    let source_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 1.
    let mint_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 2.
    let destination_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 3.
    let authority_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 4.
    let token_program_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 5.
    let base_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 6.
    let pda_account_info = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?; // 7.

    let source_account = Account::unpack(&source_info.try_borrow_data()?)?;
    let amount = source_account.amount;

    let mint = Mint::unpack(&mint_info.try_borrow_data()?)?;
    let decimals = mint.decimals;

    invoke_signed(
        &transfer_checked(
            token_program_info.key,
            source_info.key,
            mint_info.key,
            destination_info.key,
            authority_info.key,
            &[],
            amount,
            decimals,
        )
        .unwrap(),
        &[
            source_info.clone(),
            mint_info.clone(),
            destination_info.clone(),
            authority_info.clone(),
            token_program_info.clone(),
            pda_account_info.clone(),
            base_account_info.clone(),
        ],
        &[&[base_account_info.key.as_ref(), seed.as_bytes(), &[bump]]],
    )?;
},
```

Execution of the code return the Error:
`Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the `authority_info` is already funded with the token, and the right one truely derived from the bump you are sending through instruction parameter.

Instead of taking both `bump` and `seed` parameters, you should only take one `bump` parameter, and calculate `seed` from it on execution.
You can add validation step whether the attended authority key is the true one like following;

```
        // Get authority PDA and bump seed.
        let (authority_key, seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[bump],
            program_id,
        );
        if authority_key != *authority_info.key {
            return Err(ProgramError::InvalidSeeds);
        }
```

Further you can use the seed to invoke the transfer instruction of token or token-2022 program.

```
        let result = invoke_signed(
            &transfer_checked(
                token_program_info.key,
                source_info.key,
                mint_info.key,
                destination_info.key,
                authority_info.key,
                &[],
                amount,
                decimals,
            ).unwrap(),
            &[
                source_info.clone(),
                mint_info.clone(),
                destination_info.clone(),
                authority_info.clone(),
            ],
            &[&[bump, &[seed]]],
        );
```

Comment: In the function `invoke_signed ` parameter `signers_seeds` should contain the seed and bump of the authority account of the token I want to transfer?

What if I don't know the seed and bump of the authority account of the token I want to transfer, I can't transfer this token anyway?

Comment: Yes, you should send `seed` and `bump` to `signers_seeds`.
If you don't know the bump of a PDA, you cannot take token out of it unless another specific key is approved for the token owned by the PDA.

Comment: So how I can use a Token, which was created by another person, when only this persons knows seed of the authority account? I think you don't understand what I am talking about